Could not load content for webpack://SwaggerUIBundle/src/core/system.js" error in Swagger UI
While attempting to use Swagger UI to document a Laravel project with the URL http://localhost:8014/api/documentation, I encounter the following error in the browser console:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'type' of 'u' as it is undefined.
    at build-request.js:115:9
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at build-request.js:107:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at applySecurities (build-request.js:106:12)
    at buildRequest (build-request.js:16:9)
    at Object.execute_buildRequest [as buildRequest] (index.js:249:11)
    at actions.js:453:24
    at index.js:174:16
    at redux.mjs:331:12

Of course, with further investigation, I realized that the main error was:
Could not load content for webpack://SwaggerUIBundle/src/core/system.js (Fetch through target failed: Unsupported URL scheme; Fallback: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

This error only occurs for specific API endpoints, not all of them.
Additional Information:

I am using Laravel and Swagger UI in my project.
I can access the API documentation at http://localhost:8014/api/documentation.
I have carefully reviewed the API data structure, and it matches the Swagger documentation.
I am using compatible versions of Laravel and Swagger UI.
I have cleared the Swagger cache and regenerated the
documentation.

What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

I found that the problem was the authorization option that I should have added as an annotation like this :
 * @OA\SecurityScheme(
 *     securityScheme="bearerAuth",
 *     type="http",
 *     scheme="bearer"
 * )

That's why I had problems only for some routes
